# How to insert random number after text using sed

Tags: random, sed

I'd like to insert a random number after specific text using a shell script. I can generate a random number (32 char):

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1
```

How do I insert this random number (32_char_random_number) after text (e.g. "alphabet" in a file?:

```
sed '/\balphabet \b/& 32_char_random_number/' file
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Answer (score 1):

Assumed your rand number is assigned to `$char_random_number`.

```
char_random_number=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
```

And you may use double quote to access the variable,

```
sed "s/\(alphabet\)/\1$char_random_number/g" file
```

Comment: You probably should add -r when run sed

Comment: with -r option, extended regular expressions allowed. But no need to add for my answer. :)

Comment: Will it substitute \1 without -r?

Comment: Yes, it will. And with -r, no need to escape the parentheses that embraced the portion matched.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to align comments properly :(
Hm. Interesting.

    $ echo "alphabet" | sed "s/\(a.*\)/\1$char_random_number/g"
    alphabet123
    $ echo "alphabet" | sed "s/(a.*)/\1$char_random_number/g"
    sed: -e expression #1, char 15: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
    $ echo "alphabet" | sed -r "s/(a.*)/\1$char_random_number/g"
    alphabet123
Good to know :)
If you don't escape brackets, it doesn't work without -r. In your case you really don't need it

Comment: Thank you! Will confirm tomorrow and +1.

Comment: It worked, thanks again. A simpler question - what if I want to insert char_random_number 5 spaces after alphabet?

Comment: Do you mean `sed "s/\(alphabet\)/\1     $char_random_number/g"`?? There are 5 spaces between `\1` and `$char_random_number`

Answer (score 0):

Robust **awk** solution:

Sample `input.txt` contents:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor alphabet sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit alphabet. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et alphabet magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, alphabet ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, alphabet pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. 
Donec pede justo, fringilla no alphabet vel, aliquet nec, alphabet vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
Nullam dictum felis eu pede alphabet mollis pretium. 
Integer tincidunt, alphabet. Cras dapibus.
```

---

The job:

```
rnum=$(< /dev/urandom  tr -dc [[:alnum:]] | head -c 32)
awk -v rnum="$rnum" '{ gsub(/\<alphabet\>/,"& "rnum) }1'
```

---

The output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Donec quam felis, alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. 
Donec pede justo, fringilla no alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 vel, aliquet nec, alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
Nullam dictum felis eu pede alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5 mollis pretium. 
Integer tincidunt, alphabet g9vgamG[slhPKJgOxqphM[KFOdL1qDo5. Cras dapibus.
```

Comment: Thank you, will confirm tomorrow.